# Twitter kit - Redirection after authorization is not working on iOS 11 beta

Tags: ios, twitter-oauth

Always getting below error after login success not getting redirected to my app.it is keep on loading.

```
"Redirecting you back to the application.This may take a few moments."
```

[TwitterKit] did encounter error with message "Unable to authenticate using the system account.": Error Domain=TWTRLogInErrorDomain Code=0 "User denied access to system accounts." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=User denied access to system accounts., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Give this user access to the System Twitter account.}

ViewController.m

```
     [[Twitter sharedInstance] startWithConsumerKey:@"myConsumerKey" consumerSecret:@"myConsumerSecret"];
    [[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
        if (session) {
            
            TWTRComposer *composer = [[TWTRComposer alloc] init];
            
            [composer setText:@"just setting up my Twitter Kit"];
            [composer setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"twitterkit"]];
            
            // Called from a UIViewController
            [composer showFromViewController:delegate.window.rootViewController completion:^(TWTRComposerResult result) {
                if (result == TWTRComposerResultCancelled) {
                    NSLog(@"Tweet composition cancelled");
                }
                else {
                    NSLog(@"Sending Tweet!");
                }
            }];
            
        } else {
            NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
        options:(NSDictionary *) options
 {

[[Twitter sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url options:options];
return YES;
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but this may help someone, I had the same issue since from iOS 13 we have scenedelegate file. the solution for me was to manage the method in scenedelegate file via the below delegate method for twitter.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    if let openURLContext = URLContexts.first {
        let url = openURLContext.url
        let options: [AnyHashable : Any] = [
            UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation : openURLContext.options.annotation as Any,
            UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication : openURLContext.options.sourceApplication as Any,
            UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.openInPlace : openURLContext.options.openInPlace
        ]
        TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().application(UIApplication.shared, open: url, options: options)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from iOS 11, Apple has removed social accounts from iOS.

You should use Twitter Kit 3 for iOS.

Refer to Twitter blog https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/migrate-social-framework

**UPDATE**

AppDelegate

```
import TwitterKit

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
// Intialize Twitter Kit
        Twitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey:consumer_key, consumerSecret:consumer_secret)
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        if Twitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options) {
            return true
        }

 return false
}
```

ViewController

```
import TwitterKit

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Twitter.sharedInstance().logIn(with: self, completion: { (session, error) in

            if let sess = session {
                print("signed in as \(sess.userName)");
            } else {
                print("error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))");
            }
        })

    }
```

Info.plis

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>twitterkit-{your consumer key}</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>twitter</string>
        <string>twitterauth</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: yeah referred that link only not getting redirected

Comment: I tried using the Twitter login method with ViewController and the login was success and redirected successfully. Tested on iPhone 7 Plus/iOS 11 Simulator.
    - (void)logInWithViewController:(nullable UIViewController *)viewController completion:(TWTRLogInCompletion)completion;

Comment: i tried in simulator. so twitter app is not installed.

Comment: can you share me the sample project link which you done?

Comment: https://www.zipshare.com/download/eyJhcmNoaXZlSWQiOiI1MmU1M2U2ZS00ZDg2LTRhODQtOTMzYi03MWY5ZTlmYzliZmUiLCJlbWFpbCI6InBsYXlhY3JvQHlhaG9vLmNvbSJ9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153225/discussion-between-basheer-and-ravindhiran).

Comment: I've done everything but when I call login nothing happens. Completion handler is not called (not even with an error). I'm on iOS 11, any idea what would be happening?

Comment: @e.ozmen yes, it was my bad. I was custom-handling all `openURL:` requests app-wise, twitter was internally invoking a URL open request but I was ignoring the openURL: request, thus, nothing was happening. I've checked for twitter case and delegated the call to twitter api and it started working.

Comment: Why all of you are exposing `consumer secret` to apps' code, that can be reverse-engineered?